# PHP session dies in html template

Tags: php, html, perl, templates, session

I am using a php website to open a session using session_start. The customer logs in, goes to a page, and this uses forms to sends their username and other options (from a mysql db) to a CGI script which creates a report them using HTML::Template.

Once the report has generated, the customer is then presented with this report which is made to look as part of the website. However, now they're session is lost, and they are shown to no longer be logged in.

I've tried adding  at the start of the template file, but template files do not like PHP. I've also tried embedded the PHP as a TMPL_VAR but no joy.

Can anyone help? :)

Comment: You need to post your source code.  See the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Are you not using cookie-based sessions?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a PHP based system to deliver content to the user, then stick to that throughout.

Either rewrite the Perl in PHP, or refactor it so you can use it as a webservice and then write a PHP client for that.